# Relative CSS/JS path form one directory up

Tags: php, css, amazon-web-services, web, relative-path

I am using AWS to host my website.
My domain is pointing to

```
/root/code/website/
```

Now i want to put user realted custom CSS to this path

`/root/code/resources/`
I have tried

```
<link href="../resources/1111.css">
```

but its not working. Is there any way to include these css files to my PHP scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configured your AWS. First of all you need allow permission via nginx, apache to directory outside of your project (/root/code/resources/). Then configured nginx or apache server

Example for Nginx

```
location ~* \.(css) {
    root /root/code/resources/;
}
```

and your path will be

```
  <link href="1111.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you php file's path is

```
/root/code/website/index.php
```

and for CSS

`/root/code/resources/custom-styles.css`

then `<link href="../resources/custom-styles.css">` will work fine, unless this file is not the file which is being served, i.e if this file is getting included in some other file, the path should be w.r.t that file

i.e for file

```
/root/code/website/dist/index.php
```

`<link href="../../resources/custom-styles.css">` will work.

Comment: Its working in all other cases, but here my domain is pointing to /root/code/website/

Comment: if you can drop a link to file you're getting error with